# what is matrix : each row vector is rotated two(and more such $k$) element to the right relative to the preceding row vector?

Tags: linear-algebra

**In linear algebra,  if  each row vector is rotated one element to the right relative to the preceding row vector,we call this matrix is  a circulant matrix (is a special kind of Toeplitz matrix)**
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix

My question: if  each row vector is rotated  **two(and more such $k$)** element to the right relative to the preceding row vector, this matrix have name? and this case have some paper to research it?

Thank you  very much!

Answer (score 2):

It's called an anti-circulant matrix.

Comment: with this anti-cirulant matrix, have some paper? Thank you